# How to set "VisibleDate" property of asp:Calendar control?

Tags: asp.net, calendarextender

I am developing a ASP.NET web site, in which I have used a AJAX control Tool kit's CalendarExtender to select a date in asp:TextBox. I want to set the **VisibleDate** property of the asp:Calendar control based on the selected date from the CalendarExtender control. I request you to help me to achieve this functionality.
Or Is there any way to post back the page on selection of date from CalendarExtender control so that I can handle **TextChanged** event in the codebehind and set the **VisibleDate** property at within this event handler?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an asynchronous postback on TextChanged-event to set the VisibleDate property:

aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UdpDatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"  >
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1"  runat="server" />
      <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDate" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
      <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="TxtDate" runat="server" />
   </ContentTemplate> 
   <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TxtDate" EventName="TextChanged" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

codebehind:

```
Public Partial Class CalendarDemo
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub TxtDate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxtDate.TextChanged
        Dim d As Date
        If Date.TryParse(Me.TxtDate.Text, d) Then
            Me.Calendar1.VisibleDate = d
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

On this way it keeps performant and you don't have to mess around with javascript that might change in future releases of asp.net-ajax toolkit.

Comment: Thanx Tim.. your suggestion worked for me. Only difference in my case is the asp:Calendar control is not in the same UpdatePanel. It is place in different UpdatePanel without any special attributes.